# MYSQL - ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN AFTER

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am trying to change the order of the columns in a table.

To this aim i am using the following instruction :

```
ALTER TABLE `my_database`.`my_table_name` 
CHANGE COLUMN `T 11 max(Recorder)` AFTER `T 11 min(Recorded)`;
```

The error i am getting is this :

> 07:43:45  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '`T 11 min(Recorded)`' at line 1   0.000 sec

I have tried with different types of quotes characters. Also the columns have the same type.

It seems to me that there is a syntax error that i cannot find. Everything should be ok according to : [Help for alter table function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)

Thank for the input,
Andrew

Comment: what is your table's structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE `my_database`.`my_table_name` 
CHANGE COLUMN `T 11 max(Recorder)` `T 11 max(Recorder)` 
<datatype of T 11 max(Recorder) col here> AFTER `T 11 min(Recorded)`;
```